# Linting All JS files in Project Package ::JSHINT

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp-jshint

I am using the gulp task runner. For the static code analysis I am trying to use JsHint. The issue here is that I am able to run only one file at a time.

npm installation has added "gulp-jshint": "~1.11.0", in devDependensies in package.json.

```
scripts {
     "lint" : "jshint <path/file.js>"
}
```

This is very tedious to look up for every js file in the project package.

**I am looking for ways to lint all my package js files and log their report in a separate file.**

Answer (score 0):

One minute of googleing got this here http://www.codereadability.com/jshint-with-grunt/#runningjshintonmultiplefilesatonce

So `app/**/*.js` could do the trick.

Comment: yes. I have looked into those but they don't seem to work. I have added that into the scripts but upon running it shows cant open path/**/*.js.
But it does works with *.js only in the current directory and not in the sub folders.